Digital Signal Processing with Gnuradio - output signals differs from input signal without any modification done
I am sorry for the probably pretty basic question (and not very specific title) - still new to DSP and I have no idea what causes my problem.
I am using gnu radio companion and trying to a rather simple task: I have one signal and I want to know whether below or above the center frequency is an active signal. So I up- and downshifted the two signals to create two new signals and used a low pass on each of them. Then I compute the energy of both signals and assign the one with a higher energy density to the output of my python block.
My problem is that my output signals differs from both input signals, which seems odd to me, since I do not modify them. To be more specific: I used a low pass filter on both input signals, so everything above the cutoff frequency appears cyan in the waterfall sink - so far, so good. But after my python block the signal has those cyan/ white horizontal stripes above the cutoff frequency.
This is the rather simple code of the python block. Since it is so simple I honestly do not even know where I could debug. I guess my fundamental understanding of signals is still capable of improvement.
Edit: The two signals do not have the same center frequency, which I figured is also the cause for the odd looking output. If anybody has a clue, I would still be interested why the spectrum of a downshifted signal looks wider than the upshifted (- upshifted/ downshifted from the original signal) when the samples of both signals are mixed together. Always taking the sample which currently has the higher energy density.
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr
import pmt


class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block

    def __init__(self):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Level 0',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.complex64, np.complex64],
            out_sig=[np.complex64]
        )
        # register message port
        # self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern('level_1'))


    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        in0 = input_items[0][:]
        in1 = input_items[1][:]

        # check which signal has more energy
        energy0 = np.sum((in0)**2)
        energy1 = np.sum((in1)**2)

        # if energy1 has more energy, signal's frequency is higher 
        if energy1 > energy0:
            # send message
            # self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern('level_1'), 8e5)
            output_items[0][:] = in1
        else:
            output_items[0][:] = in0

        return len(output_items[0])





there is no "appended screenshot"  2) can't see error here, maybe add some minimal, reproducible example 3) I suggest debugging your code and watching your signals to see when they get modified


I noticed too late that stack overflow permitted me to add pictures, sorry. I described the differences of the 3 waterfall sinks instead. I use the 3 waterfall sinks directly before and directly after the python block. So there is not really any other possible source, which could cause this error.

screenshot recovered
